# Expo: Get audio data realtime and send via Socket.IO

Tags: react-native, socket.io, expo, sound-recognition, expo-av

### App I want to make

I would like to make audio recognition mobile app like [Shazam](https://www.shazam.com/) with

- Expo
- Expo AV(https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/audio)
- Tensorflow serving
- Socket.IO

I want to send recording data to machine learning based recognition server via Socket.IO every second or every sample (Maybe it is too much to send data sample-rate times per second), and then mobile app receives and shows predicted result.

### Problem

How to get data while recording from `recordingInstance` ? I read Expo audio document, but I couldn't figure out how to do it.

### So far

I ran two example:

- https://github.com/expo/audio-recording-example
- https://github.com/expo/socket-io-example

Now I want to mix two examples. Thank you for reading. If I could `console.log` recording data, it would help much.

### Related questions

- https://forums.expo.io/t/measure-loudness-of-the-audio-in-realtime/18259
  This might be impossible (to play animation? to get data realtime?)
- https://forums.expo.io/t/how-to-get-the-volume-while-recording-an-audio/44100
  No answer
- https://forums.expo.io/t/stream-microphone-recording/4314
  According to this question,
  https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-recording
  seems to be a solution, but it requires eject.

Comment: I wrote app by react-native, not with Expo.

Comment: Any solution for this ?

Comment: I eventually solved by requesting every 5 seconds to a server without making a socket connection.

Comment: @Watanabe.N Did you use `expo` eventually? Can you share a minimum working example, or guide me to relevant docs? I'm trying to deal with expo audio but the official docs are very unclear

Comment: @MrBens I gave up realtime socket.io, and ended up sending the last 5 seconds of the recordings at every 2.5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a good solution to this problem.

```
await recordingInstance.prepareToRecordAsync(recordingOptions);
recordingInstance.setOnRecordingStatusUpdate(checkStatus);
recordingInstance.setProgressUpdateInterval(10000);
await recordingInstance.startAsync();
setRecording(recordingInstance);
```

Above after creating and preparing for recording, I added a callback function that runs every 10 seconds.

```
const duration = status.durationMillis / 1000;
const info = await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(recording.getURI());
const uri = info.uri;
console.log(`Recording Status: ${status.isRecording}, Duration: ${duration}, Meterring: ${status.metering}, Uri: ${uri}`)
if(duration >10 && duration - prevDuration > 0){
            sendBlob(uri);
        }
 setPrevDuration(duration);
```

The callback function checks if the duration is greater than 10 seconds and the difference between last duration is greater than 0, then sends the data through WebSocket.

Currently only problem, it doesn't run the callback the first time but runs the second time.